# Methods in Python 2.7 that enable text extraction from multiple HTML pages with different element tags?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I primarily work in Python 2.7. I'm trying to extract the written content (body text) of hundreds of articles from their respective URLs. To simplify things, I've started by trying to extract the text from just one website in my list, and I've been able to do so successfully using BeautifulSoup4. My code looks like this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://insertaddresshere'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'utf-8')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup((response),"html.parser")

texts = soup.find_all("p")

for item in texts:
    print item.text
```

This gets me the body text of a single article. I know how to iterate through a csv file and write to a new one, but the list of sites I need to iterate through are all from different domains, so the HTML code varies a lot. Is there any way to find body text from multiple articles that have different element labels (here, "p") for said body text? Is it possible to use BeautifulSoup to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is. That'd be a machine learning algorithm. You could use some sort of heuristic that scores a text to non text node ratio, to try to guess the main tag.

Comment: Thanks for your response, xvan. I've learned since posting that body text is almost universally expressed in HTML with the same element label (typically "p"), so I basically just need to use this code plus the framework for iterating through multiple URLs and it should work.

Comment: <p> tags are for paragraphs, and are not universally used nor required in valid html text. You can extract the plain text (removing all tags), from any html node in the hierarchy, by using the .text decorator. I thought you were asking how to differentiate the real content of, say, a blog post, from the comments section, the adds, the index, etc.

Comment: Oh, I've confused myself quite a bit, then... I will look into .text decorator. Thanks again!